# Как сделать колбэк только тогда когда загрузятся картинки с get запроса

Tags: javascript, ajax, get, axios, blade

Я делаю запрос на адрес `return` которой возвращает сгенерированный html.
код запросa выглядит так:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    axios.get("/get-cards")
        .then(response => {
            document.getElementById("load").remove();
            $("#content").html(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(`ERROR: ${error}`);
        });
});
```

страница которая генерирует html (по адресу /get-cards) выглядит так:

```html
@foreach($technics as $technic)
    <div class="technic-card">
        <div class="card-img">
            <div style="background-image: url('{{ $technic->img_1 }}'" alt="{{ $technic->name }}">
            <div style="background-image: url('{{ $technic->img_2 }}'" alt="{{ $technic->name }}">
            <div style="background-image: url('{{ $technic->img_3 }}'" alt="{{ $technic->name }}">
        </div>
        <div class="card-name">{{ $technic->name }}</div>
        <div class="card-type">{{ $technic->type }}</div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <div class="card-price">{{ $technic->price }}/час</div>
            <div class="card-buy-btn">арендовать</div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

мне нужно чтобы на страницу добавлялся уже готовый html с загруженными картинками,
но происходит следующий сценарий.

1. загружается страница *с которой отправляется запрос и на которую
   потом ответ (html разметка) и добавляется*
2. включается индикатор загрузки
3. запрос возвращает ответ
4. индикатор загрузки убирается
5. добавляется html код на страницу
6. **и начинаются грузиться картинки** [выглядит это так](https://ru.files.fm/f/w78rjqrg)

Как сделать так чтобы индикатор загрузки не исчезал до тех пор пока не загрузятся картинки тоже?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно найти все картинки и дождаться момента когда они прогрузятся

В примере я для удобста вынес url картинок в отдельный аттрибут, но вполне можно из `element.style` получить

```js
// вместо getCards будет запрос через axios
getCards()

// когда ответ пришёл
.then(html => {
  
  $('#content').html(html);
  
  let loading = [];
  
  // ищем картинки для прогрузки
  $('#content [data-bg]').each(function(){
    loading.push(new Promise(resolve => {
      // Собираем url которые придётся грузить
      let url = $(this).data('bg');
      // создаём в памяти картинку
      let img = new Image();
      // и грузим её
      img.src = url;
      
      // когда загрузится, ставим её в background-image
      // и отчитываемся о завершении
      img.onload = () => {
        $(this).css('background-image', `url(${url})`);
        resolve();
      }
    }));
  });
  
  // когда всё загрузится
  Promise.all(loading).then(()=>{
    // убираем заглушку
    // и показываем контент
    $('#load').remove();
    $('#content').removeClass('loading');
  })
  
});




function getCards(){
  
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    
    setTimeout(()=>{
      resolve(
      
        `<div class="card">
          <div data-bg="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?r=${Math.random()}"></div>
          <div data-bg="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?r=${Math.random()}"></div>
          <div data-bg="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?r=${Math.random()}"></div>
        </div>

        <div class="card">
          <div data-bg="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?r=${Math.random()}"></div>
          <div data-bg="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?r=${Math.random()}"></div>
          <div data-bg="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150?r=${Math.random()}"></div>
        </div>
        `
      
      );
      
    },1000);
    
  })
  
}
```

```css
.loading{
  display:none;

}

[data-bg]{
  display: inline-block;
  width:70px;
  height:70px;
  background-position: center;
  background-size:cover;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="load">Loading...</div>

<div id="content" class="loading"></div>
```

Так же, можно воспользоваться плагином [waitForImages](https://github.com/alexanderdickson/waitForImages)